# ASUS Essence STX II doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 18.04, alsa, soundcard

I've just installed the ASUS Essence STX II sound card on my Ubuntu Studio system (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS).

It's detected in the audio mixer and the volume control and in `/proc/asound/cards`:

```
 0 [II             ]: AV200 - Xonar STX II

                      Asus Virtuoso 100 at 0xe000, irq 16
```

But it makes no sound at all.

Is there anything I can do, e.g. install new drivers or reinstall the ALSA-system, or is the card just broken?

Comment: Did you plug in the power cable to the sound card?

Comment: I have this [same sound card](https://i.imgur.com/hHKf4zh.png) in Ubuntu 18.04, it is working fine. It may be that there is something else wrong with your hardware.

Answer (score 0):

> When switching from Windows to Ubuntu 18.04, my sound card (Asus Xonar
>   DGX) didn’t seem to work anymore.
>
> After searching around a little bit I found a really easy fix:
>
> 1. In Settings/Sound, select Xonar DGX as the default output using the “Analog Surround 5.1 Output” profile
> 2. Launch `alsamixer` in a terminal, select the right sound card (F6), go to “Analog Output” (arrow right) and select “Multichannel” (arrow
>      up)
>
>    Now surround is working using the Xonar DGX sound card. However, even 2 channel audio was being played over all 5 speakers now. To
>      prevent “upmixing” from 2 channel audio to 5 channel audio, you can
>      disable it:
> 3. Edit `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`.
> 4. Find (or add) the `enable-remixing` setting and set it to `no`
> 5. Restart your PC

[source](https://xatom.nl/2018/05/03/xonar-dgx-ubuntu-18-04.html)

Comment: Actualy for me item number 4 not working. With 'enable-remixing=no' i have no sound ... just leave it yes and sound is ok.